# How can I modify a macro I call frequently?

Tags: elisp-macros

I use `use-package` to organize my `init.el`. I noticed that all my declarations use `:ensure t`. An example declaration is:

```
(use-package auto-complete
  :ensure t
  :diminish auto-complete-mode
  :init (global-auto-complete-mode t))
```

Since all my `use-package` declarations use `:ensure t`, is there a way to modify `use-package` to implicitly include `:ensure t` without modifying use-package.el directly? Ideally I'd like not to use a differently-named function.

I'm a little bit familiar with `advice-add`, but my impression is that this is used to add a hook or environment to a function, not to modify the function or macro itself.

Comment: Advice won't help here, as you noted: `use-package` is actually a Lisp macro. You can probably create your own `my-use-package` macro which expands to `use-package` with the default settings your prefer.

Comment: Macros can be advised also.  Case closed.

Comment: @politza True -- not sure what I was thinking. :-) Could you provide an example how that might work in this case? I suppose you could use `:filter-args` advice to add keywords like `:ensure t`?

Comment: I didn't know that either, before I read the info site about nadvice.el .

Comment: I understand the solution here works but I think the same thing to do would have been to write a wrapper function for use-package and just use that wrapper instead. It's much more clear, and it sounds like all of the code involved is under your control.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on @politza's comment that (of course!) advice works with macros, I found something that seems to work.

```
(defun use-package-always-ensure (form)
  (append form '(:ensure t)))

(advice-add #'use-package :filter-args #'use-package-always-ensure)
```

Note this example is using the Emacs 24.4 advice functions. I haven't figured out what the equivalent would be for older versions of Emacs.

Comment: I'm not really sure how this use of advice affects the behavior of byte-compiling files that use the advised macro... Can anyone comment on that?

Comment: Macros are evaluated during compilation, hence the advice must be available at compilation time, either by `require`ing a feature providing the advice, or with `eval-when-compile`.

Answer (score 5):

The [newer version](https://github.com/jwiegley/use-package) of `use-package` has the following to enable this behavior for all packages:

```
(setq use-package-always-ensure t)
```

Just in case anyone else had the same question.